# Tensor product of line bundles on K3 surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective $K3$ surface. Let $E, F, G$ be a three nonzero  ample divisors on $X$, can we put a criterion on integers $a,b,c$ such that $aE+bF+cG$ becomes base point free?

Does it only happen when $a,b,c$ are nonnegative integers?

Comment: Base point freeness for a single ample divisor is already not easy (i.e. one of $a,b,c$ positive and the other two $0$), so this seems like a tricky question. As far as I can tell, in this special case even Kawamata's base point free theorem (applied to the pair $(X,0)$ so that we just need some multiple of $E$ to be big and nef which is automatic for $E$ ample) just tells us that *some* sufficiently large multiple of $E$ is BPF.